# Stress acting at an internal point of a suspended rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity, solid-mechanics

I've come across a question that asks to calculate the stress acting at the midpoint of a uniform rod (mass $M$, length $l$ and area $A$) suspended at one end:

[image]

I know that the basic definition of stress is
$$Stress=\dfrac{Force}{Area};$$

So the first thing that came to me when I tried finding the stress at the midpoint is that the force acting at this point is the weight of the second half of the rod (below the dotted line), which is $\dfrac {Mg}{2}$. The area of cross section is given ($A$), so the stress at the midpoint will be $\dfrac{Mg}{2A}$.

The answer given says that it actually is $\dfrac {3Mg}{2A}$; that would mean I'm missing some other forces acting at the the midpoint. What am I missing?

Comment: I have removed references to the question not being a duplicate. This is up for the community to decide. Just saying a question isn't a duplicate doesn't make it so.

Comment: @AaronStevens hmmm okay, I just thought it wasn't duplicate as none of the other questions similar to this had an answer that solves my query. Yeah, it makes sense to let the community decide, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: If it isn't a duplicate then it won't be marked as such

Comment: The answer is wrong then

Comment: @SidharthGiri I'm not sure about that, you can look at it yourself [here.](https://imgur.com/Ly39QYi) I don't really understand what they did there.

Comment: I'd like to know why this post has been downvoted, haven't I already mentioned what I've tried doing? Please do mention a reason so I can improve my future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you reference says there is a mass m suspended from the rod. That makes the total weight at the mid point of the rod mg + mg/2, which leads to the stress they gave.

ADDENDUM:

In response to your following comment

***The question isn't well framed, it just says: "One end of a uniform rod of mass $m$ and cross-sectional area A is suspended from the other end. The stress at the mid-point of the rod will be __?". Your answer makes sense, what about when the attached mass M is removed? will the answer then be just mg/2? .***

The link specifically states

The weight of suspended mass is $W_{1}=mg$

The weight of  the rod at mid point is $W_{2}=\frac{mg}{2}$

Although this could definitely be worded better. It should have said there is a mass $m$ suspended at the bottom of a rod of mass $m$. But it is clear to  me they are talking about two different weights $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$. If that were not the case then I agree your answer of $\frac{mg}{2}$ would apply.

Hope this helps

Comment: The question isn't well framed, it just says: "One end of a uniform rod of mass M and cross-sectional area A is suspended from the other end. The stress at the mid-point of the rod will be __?".
Your answer makes sense, what about when the attached mass M is removed? will the answer then be just mg/2?

Comment: See my ADDENDUM to my answer. And I agree your question should not have been down voted simply because of difficulty in interpreting the question. Also, I'm not sure why my answer was down voted.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense now. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @ExtremeRaider Then you accept my answer?

Comment: yes I just did, thanks again.

Comment: Thank you also.